# Marshmallow schema from pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic, marshmallow

Given `pydantic` models, what are the best/easiest ways to generate equivalent `marshmallow` schemas from them (if it's even possible)?

I found [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/kmatarese/a5492f4a02449e13ea85ace8801b8dfb) and some other similar links which do the opposite (generate `pydantic` models from `marshmallow` schemas), but couldn't manage to find the direction I need.